# Website stretching and shrinking on mobile

Tags: html, css, viewport

I have a website that has a container in the middle of 800px, it has auto margins on both sides so it stays in the center.

Now what I want to do is to have the page be displayed withouth the left and right margined sides on mobiles, so basically I want to have it stretch out the 800px to the device width on mobile and tablet devices.

I tried using viewport meta tags but they don't seem to do much:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=800, initial-scale=1">
```

I think this just keeps the width to 800 when the devices has lesser pixels, but it will just keep my margins when the device has higher pixels

I also tried:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

But it seemed to behave exactly the same way.

I am using c# asp.net and i can detect what my device is and change the viewports accordingly, so if I am using a desktop or laptop browser I will use a different viewport meta. I just can't figure out how to ge the result I want on mobile.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make a fiddle of it and let us know

Answer (score 0):

Css media querys to change the layout depending on width will help.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 900px){
 #div_to_hide{display:none;}
  }
```

Further reading:[CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: No that just seperates css depending on width sizes. I am talking about stretching and scaling to a fixed 800 width

Comment: Could you not adjust it to make the content width 100% on certain devices? According to your question " I want to have it stretch out the 800px to the device width on mobile and tablet devices." then this would work. Have a look at the link I sent, select device width that you want the div to expand to 100% Hide the margins on both sides and violla..